# Saving file using dialog utility

Tags: linux, bash, unix, dialog, save

i am still new to terminal and i can not find way to save a file after editing with dialog utility.

```
#dialog --no-lines --title 'Name' --backtitle 'program' --editbox /etc/passwd 30 70
```

Maybe you could help me to save this edite file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `dialog` manpage: *"On exit, the contents of the edit window are written to dialog's
 output."*

So you should redirect the output of your `dialog` command to a file and use it based on the return code.

Comment: thanks i was also reading about that at the moment, hope ill manage to do that

Answer (score 0):

```
tempfile="/tmp/tmp.tmp" ## to make a temp file you can also use mktemp
filex="/path/file to be edited"
dialog --editbox "$filex" 28 125 2> "$tempfile"
returncode=$?               
if [ $returncode -eq 0 ] ; then
  rm "$filex"
  mv "$tempfile" "$filex" 
fi
```